# Distance between a line and a specified waypoint in lat long

Tags: coordinate-system, geotools

I'm based in the UK and I'm trying to determine the distance in meters between a line (created via a set of lat lng waypoints) and a specific point (also defined in lat lng).I've had a look at a couple of the posts here and come up with the following code.The distance I'm looking for is the shortest distance between the line and the specified waypoint.

I'm using org.geottols and com.vividsolutions.jts implementation.

Can someone please verify if I've done this right?

```
    double distance = 0.0;GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

    Point startPoint = geometryFactory
            .createPoint(new Coordinate(prow.getStartLatitude(), prow.getStartLongitude()));
    Point endPoint = geometryFactory
            .createPoint(new Coordinate(prow.getFinishLatitude(), prow.getFinishLongitude()));

    List<WayPoint> waypoints = getWaypoints(prow);

    int length = waypoints.size() + 2;
    Coordinate[] coords = new Coordinate[length];
    coords[0] = startPoint.getCoordinate();

    Point[] waypointList = new Point[length];
    waypointList[0] = startPoint;
    waypointList[length - 1] = endPoint;

    int i = 1;
    for (Iterator<WayPoint> iterator = waypoints.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        WayPoint wayPoint = (WayPoint) iterator.next();
        Point wp = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(wayPoint.getLatitude(), wayPoint.getLongitude()));
        waypointList[i] = wp;
        coords[i] = wp.getCoordinate();
        i = i + 1;

    }

    coords[length - 1] = endPoint.getCoordinate();

    Point targetWaypoint = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(waypointLat, waypointLng));

    LineString route = geometryFactory.createLineString(coords);
    route = (LineString) Densifier.densify(route, .01);

    try {

        CRSAuthorityFactory crsFac = ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactory("EPSG", null);
        CoordinateReferenceSystem wgs84crs = crsFac.createCoordinateReferenceSystem("4326");
        MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84, wgs84crs);
        Geometry prowLine = JTS.transform(route, transform);
        Geometry waypoint = JTS.transform(targetWaypoint, transform);

        Double degrees = prowLine.distance(waypoint);
        // g3.isWithinDistance(g4, distance);

        distance = degrees  * (3.14159/180) * 6371;

        Coordinate[] c = DistanceOp.nearestPoints(waypoint, prowLine);

        Coordinate c1 = new Coordinate();
        // System.out.println(c[1].distance(g4.getCoordinate()));
        JTS.transform(c[1], c1, transform.inverse());
        // System.out.println(geometryFactory.createPoint(c1));
        distance = JTS.orthodromicDistance(targetWaypoint.getCoordinate(), c1, DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return distance;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the easiest or cleanest way to do this.

First:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem wgs84crs = crsFac.createCoordinateReferenceSystem("4326");
        MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84, wgs84crs);
```

is an identity transform (with a possible axis swap) as both source and target are EPSG:4326. Also that is a geographic projection so it's not well suited to this sort of calculation. Apart from that it is fine, provided that the distances are small and your route doesn't cross the anti-meridian or the poles all should be fine.

Since you state you are in the UK it may be easier to reproject in the OS National Grid coordinates and work in a flat cartesian space. I ran the following to test:

```
  CoordinateReferenceSystem auto = CRS.decode("epsg:27700");
  MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84, auto);
  Geometry g3 = JTS.transform(point2, transform);
  Geometry g4 = JTS.transform(point, transform);
  double dist1 = g3.distance(g4);
  System.out.println("epsg27700: " + dist1);
  dist = JTS.orthodromicDistance(point.getCoordinate(), point2.getCoordinate(), DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
  System.out.println("ortho " + dist);
```

and got:

```
epsg27700: 2289.97m
ortho      2290.35m
```

which are close enough to identical for points measured with a GPS.

Comment: Thanks Ian. If I set to eps:27700 I get an exception and error - "org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException: The transform result may be 102,436.889 meters away from the expected position. Are you sure that the input coordinates are inside this map projection area of validity? The point is located 55°33.0'E away from the central meridian and 49°53.8'S away from the latitude of origin. The projection is "Transverse_Mercator". The precision for ortho is close enough for my purposes. Could you please share your test inputs?

Comment: you have lat and lon switched - 55 is N in the UK not E

Comment: thanks Ian. Swapped the constructor for Coordiante to be longitude then latitude, now get this:- org.geotools.referencing.operation.projection.ProjectionException: The transform result may be 0 meters away from the expected position. Are you sure that the input coordinates are inside this map projection area of validity? The point is located 2°07.8'E away from the central meridian and 4°31.0'N away from the latitude of origin. The projection is "Transverse_Mercator".

Comment: This link is suggesting eastings and northing but I'm working in lat log?

Comment: Thanks Ian - please ignore my last comment, found the issue......working treat now...thanks.